# Pivot table : absolute value of grand total in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting, pivot-table

My grant total is generated by summing values of COLUMNS of ITEMS for a given SUBJECT (For each SUBJECT I have a list of ITEMS and I want to make a grand total of the values of these ITEMS). The values for the items can take negative values and my grand total should be the sum of positive and negative values. I need to select top 20 rows according to the absolute value of grand value. The solution has to be dynamic - I can't copy value from Pivot Table to separate sheet and sort it there. I tried to define “Calculated Field” as `=ABS(SUM(VALUE))` but it sums absolutes of a values for ITEMS.

Comment: Does a "dynamic" solution rule out adding a column/field to your source data?

Comment: If you're pulling a total, can't you edit the field settings to be absolute value?

Comment: @Excelll - unfortunately yes. Raystafarian - abs is not available option in field settings

Comment: How about if you insert a `calculated field` or a `calculated item` you could use the existing sum field and give it `abs`

Comment: Can you post a picture of the current layout or at least explain a little more about what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is identified by Microsoft... see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211470/en-us.

But I think a way to achieve this is to use an calculated item in the pivot. For example, if you have a dataset like this :

```
id | value
--
1  | 300 
--
2  | -400
--
3  | -500
--
4  | 600
--
```

A calculated item with this formula : `=SUM(ABS(id[1])+ABS(id[2])+ABS(id[3])+ABS(id[4]))` will produce a result of 1800, instead of 0 with the pivot table grand total. Notice that you need to have an "id" column in your data set. In the calculated field, `id[i]`, with `i`indicate the item number as appears in the pivot table. For your case you have to iterate the formula until 20.

If you have a lot of rows or if the number of rows can vary, you could look to a macro for build automatically the calculated item.

Comment: Remember to properly format your question. Use a right angle bracket `>` before each line of a block quote, and indent code blocks with four spaces.